# Error Undefined is not function when click on notification react native onesignal

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I am using One signal react native library to receive notification, Everything is working fine even I receive notification but the issue is when I want to open specific screen. When I click on notification I get an Undefined error here is my code.

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.init("key");

    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
      OneSignal.removeEventListener('ids', this.onIds);
  }

  onReceived(notification) {
      console.log("Notification received: ", notification);
  }

  onOpened(openResult) {
    console.log('Message: ', openResult.notification.payload.body);
    console.log('Data: ', openResult.notification.payload.additionalData, openResult.notification.payload.additionalData.catalog);
    console.log('isActive: ', openResult.notification.isAppInFocus);
    console.log('openResult: ', openResult);

    //if (typeof openResult.notification.payload.additionalData.catalog !== 'undefined'){
      this.props.navigation.navigate('CatalogInfo', {
        query: openResult.notification.payload.additionalData.catalog,
      });
    //}
  }

  onIds(device) {
    console.log('Device info: ', device);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <RootStack />
    );
  }
}

const NavigationScreen = createStackNavigator(
  {
      Login: LoginScreen,
      Register: RegisterScreen
  }
)

const CustomDrawerComp = (props) => (
  <SafeAreaView styles={{flex: 1}}>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)


const MainApp = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
      Home: HomeScreen,
      Setting: SettingScreen,
      CatalogInfo: CatalogInfoScreen,
      Slider: ImageSlider,
      Category: CategoryScreen
  },
  {
      contentComponent: CustomDrawerComp
  }
)

const RootStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: MainApp,
    Auth: NavigationScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

Even when I click on the notification this.props.navigation is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried to do this in the App.js, but the navigation is not working there, at least to add params there.

So I ended up storing it with AsyncStorage and on my home component (first screen), loading the data from the AsyncStorage and if it contains data, navigating to the specific screen.

The navigation works, only the onOpened doesn't run when I click the notification and the app is closed. The app opens as normal, but no navigating. Closing the app again, and reopen it, shows the specific screen for me with the notification text.